# Argue for that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2x}$ is convergent if and only if $x>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Consider the series
$$
S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2x}
$$
then I have to argue for that $S$ is convergent if and only if $x>0$.

As this is if and only if I think I have to assume first that S is convergent and show that this implies that $x>0$ but I am not sure how to. It is easy for me see that if $x=0$ the series is divergent but if I were to assume that S is convergent and that for a contradiction that $x\leq 0$ how do I proceed? And how the other way around?

Do you mind helping me?

Comment: If $S$ is convergent then $e^{-n^2x}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, which happens when $x>0$, so that $-n^2x\to -\infty$

Comment: What is the limit of individual terms of a convergent sequence? Would these terms have that limit if $x < 0$?

Comment: By root test the series is convergent.

Comment: Is it possible to use that if x>0 this must mean that every tail of S is convergent. Thus S itself must be convergent. Or do I have to use contraposition?

Answer (score 1):

If S is convergent then $e^{-n^2x}\to 0$, which it only does if $x>0$.
If $x\le 0$ then $-n^2x\ge 0$ and hence $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} e^{-n^2x}\ge \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} e^{0}= \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}1=\infty$. (contraposition)

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to use that if $x>0$ this must mean that every tail of S is convergent. Thus S itself must be convergent. Or do I have to use contraposition?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see it is to compare the sum in question to the integral

$$
\int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-(t\sqrt{x})^2} dx =\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{\infty} e^{-s^2} ds
$$
Which exists only for $x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x>0$, then (since $0<e^{-x}<1$)
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {e^{ - n^2 x} }  \le \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {e^{ - nx} }  = \frac{{e^{ - x} }}{{1 - e^{ - x} }} = \frac{1}{{e^x  - 1}} <  + \infty .
$$
If $x\leq 0$, the terms do not tend to zero, whence the series cannot converge.

Comment: But am I able to use that if $x>0$ this must mean that every tail of $S$ is convergent? Thus S itself must be convergent?

Comment: You do not have to say anything about tails. The infinite sum is bounded, whence converges.

Answer (score 0):

If the series converges $\implies \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-n^{2}x} = 0$. Do you see why $x$ needs to be positive now?

Comment: Yes, thank you!